# How to test 3528 smd LED

Tags: led, pcb, diodes, multimeter, testing

Using my DMM and the diode selector, the SMDs 3528 in a brand new Led bulb does not light. I used this method to test the classic "round" leds but in this case it does not work. What seems to be wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you show a schemaic of what you are using?

Comment: hi, it is just a brand new led commerical bulb.

Comment: @Maverick that doesn't help at all. Can you draw a schematic?

Answer (score 2):

The forward voltage of the LED might be higher than the test voltage of the multimeter, usualy red LEDs have the lower forward voltage and blue and white ones have the higher voltage.

Comment: so you mean thay my DMM does not have enough voltage at the diode selector to activate the led, right? If yes how to test it ?

Comment: @Maverick You could use a battery of a suitable voltage and an appropriate current-limiting resistor.